# how to update a column without changing the others in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hbm

Please Help me as soon as possible. 
I tried with changing the hbm file configuration like dynamic-update ="true",
But it is not working.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load the entity
2. Modify the property that corresponds to that column accordingly
3. Save the entity

If you have a timestamp column (for optimisting locking) it will be modified as well, but this should not be undesirable.

IIRC dynamic-insert and dynamic-update are used to exclude null property columns from the insert / update sql statements.